# Skewness of 2-tuples?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have asked this on cross validated, but I will also ask it herer.

I have a set of $2$-tuples:

$$\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_{500},y_{500})\}$$

Where every $x_i$ is the volatility and every $y_i$ is the log return. So I am trying to gauge the link between the volatility and the returns. There is a bump in the observations for $y_i < 0.1$ (for volatilities less than $10\%$). These observations are based off a trading strategy. I am trying to understand the statistical significance of this bump. I decided to use bootstrapping, measure the skewness of observations for volatilitiles less than $10\%$ in each case, construct a cofidence interval and then see whether the original skewness falls in that confidence interval. But the question is, how do I construct a skewness measure for $2$-tupels. Here is the depiction of my results:

[image]

and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233041/bootstrapping-to-measure-the-significance-of-the-skewness) is the cross validated question.

EDIT: Ahh! Perhaps the distances of the observations of positive log returns to the horizontal axis at $0$? But that would sum the small ones as well. I suppose I would like to ignore them..

Comment: It seems to me that the x's are indeed skewed. But I suppose a histogram of the x's would _not_ show an abrupt change in density around 0.1. So I would not describe the concentration of points below 0.1 as a 'bump'. It is difficult to say whether there is a meaningful association between x and y. Certainly, the usual correlation coefficient $r$ would be very highly influenced by the high outlier at about (0.3, 10.2).

Comment: I am not sure if what I have done is very meaningful, but I have performed bootstrap sampling $10,000$ times for this data in the depiction, each time I have calculated the "skewness" measure. Which I defined as the distance of the observation to the $0$ horizontal line for all observations with log return > $0.05$ (only interested in moderate to large returns) and for volatilities < $0.1$ (due to sparsity of data beyond $0.1$). And calculated the skewness for the above, which is around $128$. The $95$% CI of the bootstrap is from around $75$ to $125$.

Comment: So I suppose I can somehow statistically justify that bump now...